# Are A and D homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpkzNeS8G20) where it's said that letters A and D as shapes are *topologically the same*. Given that this is a video about algebraic topology and likely there'll be a talk on fundamental groups etc., the authors perhaps mean homotopic equivalence rather than being homeomorphic. Yet, that made me realize that I do not know how to show that A and D are not homeomorphic to each other. Definitely the latter is just $\Bbb S^1$, and the former should have some issue due to its "legs", but what would be the formal way to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have remove two points from $D$, what remains consists of two connected sets. If you remove the extreme points of the horizontal bar of $A$, what remains has four connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for the moment that we are using sans-serif As and Ds (like what I get when I type this rather than what we see when I post this), they would not be homeomorphic. The points where the "legs" of the A join the "crossbar" do not have neighbourhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$, while every point of D has such a neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

Removal of any single point of D leaves a connected space behind.  That is not true for A.